# Substring search in Python

Tags: python, string, substring

I want to understand how the following statement works:

```
if ("ssh" or "telnet") in connection_type:
 ...
```

This seems to work similar to:

```
if any(substr in connection_type for substr in ["ssh", "telnet"]):
...
```

Is there any difference between the two statements? Thanks!

Comment: "I want to understand how the following statement works" - it doesn't. Try it with `"telnet"` in `connection_type` and `"ssh"` not in `connection_type`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a difference.

The first one seems to work but does not.

```
>>> connection_type = 'ssh'
>>> ("ssh" or "telnet") in connection_type
True

>>> connection_type = 'telnet'
>>> ("ssh" or "telnet") in connection_type
False
```

Why is this? The `or` operator in Python returns the first `True` value among the operands or the last one if all of them evaluate to `False` - that is why it only works for "ssh". You can think of `or` like the ternary operator of other languages:

```
first or second
```

Is like:

```
bool(first) ? first : second
```

The second one is right.

If `connection_type` is the whole word "telnet" or "ssh", you also can do:

```
if connection_type in ('ssh', 'telnet'):
    ...
```

If "telnet" or "ssh" are just substrings of connection_type, you can also use a regular expression:

```
if re.search(r'ssh|telnet', connection_type):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work is that the bracketed 'or' statement
is performed first given the precedence of anything within
brackets. And since both operands are strings they both
evaluate to true in python.  But what is returned is the actual value
itself which you can see if you run:

```
a=("ssh" or "telnet")
print(a)
```

you'll get "ssh".  This behaviour is called "short-circuiting"
whereby the first true value in an 'or' encountered
is returned (similarly the first false value in an 'and' statement
will be returned). Some languages that also do this will return this 'truthful'
value by converting it to an actual boolean (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)) 
- but not in pythons case.

So you'll get the first operand each time unless that value evaluates
to false under python's rules (see [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html))
and that's the value that's used for the subsequent "in" 
statement - and hence the unintuitive behavior.